# Why after .split() I got an empty &str?

Tags: rust

I want to get a square generated by "+", and here is what I thought.

1. write a function, and parameter n is side length.
2. repeat "+" n*n times, than I can got all "+"
3. split it by square's side, than I can got an array, which is made by the number of square's side.
4. Then join "\n" and to string.

For example, n = 4, so I expect a 4x4 square back just like below as a string:

```
++++
++++
++++
++++
```

Here is my code, after .split(), I got an empty array, I don't know why.

```
fn generate_square(n: i32) -> String {
    "+".repeat((n * n) as usize) //got all "+"
        .split(&*"+".repeat(n as usize)).collect::<Vec<&str>>() //got empty, why?
        .join("\n").trim_end().to_string()
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These two documents will help others answer your question quicker.

Comment: Have you read the split() documentation? The result you get is exactly as documented: The separators ('+') are not included in the results and contiguous separators result in empty strings in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `split` does.

`split` looks for instances of the pattern you supply and returns the substrings *after* resp. *before* those patterns (i.e. *not* including the pattern). I.e. if you look for "`+`" in a string "`++++`", you can only get substrings since there are no actual characters between the "`+`". I.e. in this case you get 5 empty strings.

That said: If you really want to generate the whole string and then subdivide it, you could try [`split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_at) (or others). However, depending on what you want to do, it may be easier to just generate the thing line by line.